# MySql join multiple tables with different rows number

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I'm sorry for the probably confusing title but I didn't really know how to describe my problem well.
I also appologize for my english as I'm not a native speaker.

Let's say I have this schema :

```
 _________                               _________
| Table 1 |                             | Table 2 |
|---------|          ______     ________|---------|
| id_a    |___      | join |   |        | id_b    |
| name    |   |     |------|   |        | info    |
|_________|   |_____| id_a |___|        | data    |
                    | id_b |            |_________|
                    |______|
```

With these informations in the database :

**Table 1 :**

```
 _____________
| id_a | name |
|------|------|
|   1  | foo  |
|______|______|
```

**Table 2 :**

```
 _____________________
| id_b | info | data  |
|------|------|-------|
|   1  | bar  | baz   |
|   2  | kux  | corge |
|   3  | fred | quux  |
|______|______|_______|
```

**Join :**

```
 _____________
| id_a | id_b |
|------|------|
|   1  |   1  |
|   1  |   2  |
|   1  |   3  |
|______|______|
```

In my database, I have other tables that are the same type as the *"Join"* one. They are used to store a *"Table 1"* ID and other IDs from other tables *(I used only one join table in my schema to simplify the problem)*.

When I tried to retrive the datas that I wanted, I first used this syntax :

```
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN join AS j
ON j.id_a = t1.id_a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t2.id_b = j.id_b
WHERE t1.id_a = ?
```

But as the result was an array of multiple rows while I was expecting only one single row, I tried then to use **GROUP_CONCAT**.

So my syntax became :

```
SELECT t1.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.info SEPARATOR '|') AS info,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.data SEPARATOR '|') AS data
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN join AS j
ON j.id_a = t1.id_a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t2.id_b = j.id_b
WHERE t1.id_a = ?
GROUP BY t1.id_a
```

Now it works fine and it returns a single row.

The problem now is that I'm using this principle with multiple joins and each join returns multiple rows of a different number than the others. The concatenation value is then duplicated and I can have results such as :

```
arrray(
    [...]
    'info' => 'bar|bar|bar|bar|kux|kux|kux|kux|fred|fred|fred|fred|',
    'data' => 'baz|baz|baz|baz|corge|corge|corge|corge|corge|quux|quux|quux|quux'
)
```

**So I would like to know if there is a way to avoid duplicated values and still retrieve the datas that I want in a single request ?**

Comment: I'de like to use a single request to retrieve the informations that I want without having these duplicated values in the result.

Comment: Your sample data should not be producing those duplicated results.

Comment: I agree. The duplicated results don't happend with the example that I gave but as I explained, my database is different and I use the same principle as above to join other tables that return multiple rows of different number for each join.

Comment: Is the id column on table 1 unique, and do you have a composite key on the  id's from both tables in the link entity? Looks like there are duplicate keys there, so while the below answer will give you distinct values you're much better off fixing the structure of your database schema.

Comment: **@Mhowell>** Yes sure all the IDs are unique and the table _"Join"_ has a composite key of the two foreign keys that it stores.

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, this query should be returning what you want:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.info SEPARATOR '|') AS info,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.data SEPARATOR '|') AS data
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     join j
     ON j.id_a = t1.id_a LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.id_b = j.id_b
WHERE t1.id_a = ?
GROUP BY t1.id_a;
```

If you want, you can remove the duplicates using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.info SEPARATOR '|') AS info,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.data SEPARATOR '|') AS data
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     join j
     ON j.id_a = t1.id_a LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.id_b = j.id_b
WHERE t1.id_a = ?
GROUP BY t1.id_a;
```

Typically, though, it is better to fix the query so it doesn't generate the duplicates.

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing ! It works fine but let's say that I have two or more same values for the column _"data"_ , I would then have 3 results for the column _"info"_ and only 2 for the column _"data"_. So is there a way to keep the same number of occurrences ?

Comment: @user3292788 . . . You should ask a *another* question with appropriate sample data.  (If you change this question, then it might invalidate this answer, which can draw downvotes.)  The example in this question has three different values in each column.  It is a little hard to follow what it means for the two to have different numbers of columns.

Comment: You're probably right I was going to edit my first question but as you said, there's already a right answer. So I'll start another topic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff He just posted one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949199/mysql-duplicated-values-in-a-join-using-group-concat)...I won't answer it though :-)